Evaluating $\int_0^{10} \text{sn}(x|i) \, dx$
I am trying to evaluate:
$$\int_0^{10} \text{sn}(x|i) \, dx$$
where $sn$ denotes the Jacobi elliptic function sn.
The indefinite integral is:
$$(-1)^{3/4} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \text{cd}(x|i)\right)$$
But I cannot substitute the limits to compute the definite integral because there is a discontinuity along the path around $x=7.07$. The definite integral can be computed if the point of discontinuity can be determined analytically.
Thanks for any help.

Mathematica gives: $\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{i}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{i} \text{cd}(10|i)\right)}{\sqrt{i}}$

Hmm, Mathematica seems to be disregarding the discontinuity, so this is incorrect. The numerical value of Mathematica's result is $-0.20668-0.09082 i$ whereas the correct result should be about $-2.4281-2.3122 i$

Note ... $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and we use Mathematica's convention for the parameter.  In the other convention, the integrand is $\operatorname{sn}(x,(-1)^{1/4})$.  Using this, Maple agrees with the numerical value $−2.4281−2.3122$

the discontinuity is $-\frac{(1+i) \pi }{\sqrt{2}}$, taking that into account gives the correct value for the definite integral, see https://mathoverflow.net/q/480116/11260

My humble request to the community members is please do not downvote/close questions carelessly without understanding their depths, since in this way we injure the good knowledge outlets for future readers. For this question in particular, I got a very nice answer in https://mathoverflow.net/a/480135/540668

Do you still need this question then?

@ТymaGaidash, yes let us please keep that open, since we do not know the exact point of discontinuity yet; we only know that it is around $x=7.07$; thanks
